# typeof() gets "integer" for traditional Chinese characters in R

Tags: r, class, special-characters, non-ascii-characters, typeof

### MY CODE IN R IS AS BELOW:

```
landtrading <- read.xls("landtrading/landtradingdata.xlsx")
names(landtrading) 
#[1] "GISID"  "fort"   "fortid" "jo"     "joid"   "cho"    "mktpj" 
class(landtrading$fort)
# factor
typeof(landtrading$fort)
# integer
```

### BRIEF INTRODUCTION TO THE DATASET STRUCTURE

`landtrading` is an Excel file with the historical market price for trading lands in Taiwan. `jo`,`fort`, and `cho` are administrative levels in Taiwan, basically `cho` > `fort` > `jo`.

In the excel file, the columns are

1. `GISID`, a unique ID number for each observation;
2. `fort`, the name of forts which are traditional Chinese characters;
3. `fortid`, the ID number for each fort within a `Cho`, it's a different number from the GISID;
4. `jo` is the names for each `Jo` displayed in traditional Chinese characters;
5. `joid` is ID number for each `Jo` within a fort.
6. `mktpj`, the number of market price for land.

### MY PROBLEM

As shown in the code, the column `fort` is in traditional Chinese characters, however when I use `typeof()` to get its type, it says it is an "integer". I also tried `class()`, and the output says it's a "character".

So anything wrong with my code when using `typeof()`? Why the result is wrong. It seems that `typeof()` returns "integer" for everything.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

@Roland The output of dput(head(landtrading$fort)) and sessionInfo are as below:

```
> dput(head(landtrading$fort))
  # structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("三貂堡", 
  # "下茄苳北堡", "下茄苳南堡", "二林上堡", "二林下堡", 
  # "二結堡", "五城堡", "仁和里", "仁壽上里", "仁壽下里", 
  # (too many names, so partly omitted)
  # "鯉魚頭堡", "鳳山上里", "鳳山下里", "鹽水港堡", 
  # "鹿仔草堡", "龍蛟潭堡"), class = "factor")

> sessionInfo()
  # R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
  # Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

  # locale:
  # [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

  # attached base packages:
  # [1] splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
  # [8] base     

  # other attached packages:
  # [1] gdata_2.13.3       doBy_4.5-13        survival_2.37-7        RColorBrewer_1.0-5
  # [5] plyr_1.8.1         rgdal_0.8-16       sp_1.0-17          ggplot2_1.0.0     
  # [9] foreign_0.8-61    

  # loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  # [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     grid_3.1.2       gtable_0.1.2    
  # [5] gtools_3.4.1     lattice_0.20-29  MASS_7.3-35      Matrix_1.1-4    
  # [9] munsell_0.4.2    proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2      reshape2_1.4    
  # [13] scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: Please add the output of `dput(head(landtrading$fort))` and of `sessionInfo()` to your question.

Comment: @Roland Thank you so much! Because the output is a little bit long, so I added them in my original question.

Comment: The column is of class `factor`. Since factors are `integer`s internally, that's what `typeof` reports. However, it's impossible that `class` returns `character` with this input. It must return `factor`. Therefore, I do not believe the output you show.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I guess you are right. class() returns "factor". I wrote the first section of code manually, so I made a mistake. Then how can I input the column as "character"? Thanks!

Comment: Convert them to character after reading with `with(landtrading, levels(fort)[fort])` or use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in `read.xls()`

Comment: This is essentially answered in the comments, but the OP is probably long gone. Would one of the original commenters, or @Werner, like to provide the answer for the sake of closure?

Comment: @BenBolker the original commenters should do it.